# Inequality: Find Min $S=\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-b}}$

Tags: inequality

Inequality: 
Find Min a,b>0, a+b=1. $S=\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-b}}$

Comment: By the AM-GM Inequality, this is

$$\geq \frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt[4]{(1-a)(1-b)}}.$$

Perhaps you have additional restrictions for $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$, the function $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ is convex, so using $a+b=1$, we have
$$
af(b)+bf(a)\geq f(ab+ba)=f(2ab)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2ab}}\geq\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a+b}=\sqrt{2}.
$$
The second inequality above uses $(a+b)^2\geq 4ab$. All equalities above are achieved when $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

By Holder's Inequality,
$$LHS^2\cdot(2ab)=\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt b}+\frac{b}{\sqrt a}\right)^2(ab+ba)\ge(a+b)^3=1$$

We also know $2ab\le\frac12(a+b)^2=\frac12$. Using this in the above, we get 
$$LHS\ge\sqrt2$$

As equality is obtained when $a=b=\frac12$, this is indeed then minimum.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't "Min S" if you don't have restrictions for $a$ and $b$, since $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ is an increasing function.

Note that $$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}+ x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}} {1-x}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(1-x)+\frac12} {(1-x)\sqrt{1-x}}>0$$

Comment: sorry, it was edited